# How to combine two MS SQL Server tables into one in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, union, user-defined-types

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008R2 that takes two user defined table types as parameters. Each of these types is a simple table holding an series of Ids:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Ids] AS TABLE(
    [Id] [int] NULL
)
```

I want to combine the two parameters passed in to achieve the following result:

```
DECLARE 
@Table1 TABLE (Id INT )

DECLARE
@Table2 TABLE (Id INT )


INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES (2)

INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES (11)
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES (22)


SELECT * FROM @Table1
SELECT * FROM @Table2


DECLARE
@Combined TABLE (T1 INT, T2 INT)

-- TODO: Magically combine the two tables

SELECT * FROM @Combined

-- Output would be the following

1, 11
1, 22
2, 11
2, 22
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with table-valued parameters.

Comment: Perhaps - but it's background that could lead to someone suggesting a different approach to the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want a `cross join`:

```
insert into @Combined(t1, t2)
    select t1.id, t2.id
    from @Table1 t1 cross join
         @Table2 t2;
```

Comment: +1 but I would also add a second option of doing just the SELECT and no INSERT because depending on the intended use, the SELECT with CROSS JOIN could be all that is needed and the extra Table Variable / Temp Table would just be wasted effort and resources.